# Difference between Xen PV, Xen KVM and HVM?

Tags: vps, xen, kvm-virtualization, virtualization

I know that Xen is usually better than OpenVZ as the provider cannot oversell in Xen.
However, what is the difference between `Xen PV`, `Xen KVM` and `HVM` (I was going through this provider's [specs](https://www.lightwave.net/vps-hosting.html)?  Which one is better for what purposes and why?

---

### Edit:

For an end-user who will just be hosting websites, which is better? From efficiency or other point of view, is there any advantage of one over the other?

Answer (score 50):

> Xen supported virtualization types
>
> Xen supports running two different
>   types of guests. Xen guests are often
>   called as domUs (unprivileged
>   domains). Both guest types (PV, HVM)
>   can be used at the same time on a
>   single Xen system.
>
> Xen Paravirtualization (PV)
>
> Paravirtualization is an efficient and
>   lightweight virtualization technique
>   introduced by Xen, later adopted also
>   by other virtualization solutions.
>   Paravirtualization doesn't require
>   virtualization extensions from the
>   host CPU. However paravirtualized
>   guests require special kernel that is
>   ported to run natively on Xen, so the
>   guests are aware of the hypervisor and
>   can run efficiently without emulation
>   or virtual emulated hardware. Xen PV
>   guest kernels exist for Linux, NetBSD,
>   FreeBSD, OpenSolaris and Novell
>   Netware operating systems.
>
> PV guests don't have any kind of
>   virtual emulated hardware, but
>   graphical console is still possible
>   using guest pvfb (paravirtual
>   framebuffer). PV guest graphical
>   console can be viewed using VNC
>   client, or Redhat's virt-viewer.
>   There's a separate VNC server in dom0
>   for each guest's PVFB.
>
> Upstream kernel.org Linux kernels
>   since Linux 2.6.24 include Xen PV
>   guest (domU) support based on the
>   Linux pvops framework, so every
>   upstream Linux kernel can be
>   automatically used as Xen PV guest
>   kernel without any additional patches
>   or modifications.
>
> See XenParavirtOps wiki page for more
>   information about Linux pvops Xen
>   support.
>
> Xen Full virtualization (HVM)
>
> Fully virtualized aka HVM (Hardware
>   Virtual Machine) guests require CPU
>   virtualization extensions from the
>   host CPU (Intel VT, AMD-V). Xen uses
>   modified version of Qemu to emulate
>   full PC hardware, including BIOS, IDE
>   disk controller, VGA graphic adapter,
>   USB controller, network adapter etc
>   for HVM guests. CPU virtualization
>   extensions are used to boost
>   performance of the emulation. Fully
>   virtualized guests don't require
>   special kernel, so for example Windows
>   operating systems can be used as Xen
>   HVM guest. Fully virtualized guests
>   are usually slower than
>   paravirtualized guests, because of the
>   required emulation.
>
> To boost performance fully virtualized
>   HVM guests can use special paravirtual
>   device drivers to bypass the emulation
>   for disk and network IO. Xen Windows
>   HVM guests can use the opensource
>   GPLPV drivers. See
>   XenLinuxPVonHVMdrivers wiki page for
>   more information about Xen PV-on-HVM
>   drivers for Linux HVM guests.

This is from http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/XenOverview

KVM is not Xen at all, it is another technology, where KVM is a Linux native kernel module and not an additional kernel, like Xen. Which makes KVM a better design. the downside here is that KVM is newer than Xen, so it might be lacking some of the features.

Comment: +1 KVM is not Xen at all. It totally disagree that KVM is a better design. Xen provides much better isolation and does not depend on the Linux kernel and it's potential vulnerabilites.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I couldn't understand all. From an end-user point-of-view, who will just be hosting websites, which is better? Is there significant advantage of one over the other?

Comment: Xen has it's own vulnerabilities. But running an OS with two kernels bootstrapped is a design flaw, no matter how well you do it

Comment: JP19: that depends on the websites. If you can define the load on the VPS, you can ask here or google for the best solution.

Comment: Since XEN is a hypervisor that`s the better design in my point of view. It allows for paravirtualization - which imho makes the most of your hardware.

Comment: Xen is a hypervisor, and so is KVM. KVM has PV devices, and adds more with time, it also allows PCI passthrough. So I don't see the point to your argument, Nils

Comment: @dyasny KVM is part of the Linux-kernel - a Hypervisor is a layer between hardware and kernel. But apart from that there is an open discussion which is faster. My point went into the same direction as Antoine.

Comment: @Nils hypervisor is not _between_ the kernel and the hardware, it's part of the kernel, a driver for the VT extensions if you will. Whether it's placed in a separate microkernel, like in Xen and Hyper-V or bundled in a single kernel with no extra complications, like KVM, it's still a part of _a_ kernel.

Answer (score 36):

`Xen` is an hypervisor that runs on metal (the pc / server) and then hosts virtual machines called domains.

A `Xen PV` domain is a *paravirtualized domain*, that means the operating system (usually we're talking linux here) has been modified to run under Xen, and there's no need to actually emulate hardware. This *should* be the most efficient way to go, performance wise.

A `Xen HVM` domain is *hardware emulated* domain, that means the operating system (could be Linux, Windows, whatever) has not been modified in any way and hardware gets emulated. This is rather slow, so usually you install *PV drivers* in the guest os for critical hardware (usually disk and network), so the guest as a whole will run fully virtualized but the most performance-critical pieces of hardware will run paravirtualized. Recent linux systems have pv drivers for both disk and network in the kernel, and there exist various PV drivers for Windows too.
With all the development on HVM in recent years there usually is little difference in performance between HVM and PV for standard workloads.

`KVM` is not Xen, it is another virtualization platform built inside the Linux kernel. From a *guest* point of view it resembles Xen HVM: the guest runs fully virtualized and there are specific driver to run some parts paravirtualized (again, disk and network).

Both Xen HVM and Linux KVM need hardware assisted virtualization support (Intel VT-x, AMD AMD-V), whereas Xen PV does not but can't run operating systems without PV support (you can't run Windows on Xen PV).

Both Xen HVM and Linux KVM will use parts of the qemu virtualization software to emulate actual hardware for devices not using PV drivers in the guest system.

Xen (both PV and HVM) can do live migration of a running guest from one physical server to another, I don't know if KVM can too.

Both Xen and KVM cannot overcommit memory so you usually get "true RAM", while other platforms like VMware can swap part of the guest ram to disk.

There are differences but usually apply to specific installations and not to the generic virtual private server for sale to other people. For example recent Xen hypervisors support transcendent memory that could improve memory utilization and guest performance if the guest has support for it (linux kernels >= 3.something).

All those technologies will give you a great experience if they are implemented correctly, and will not make a big difference from your point of view. Of course, there are a thousand ways things can go wrong and that's not related to the specific virtualization solution (i.e., your guest could be stored on slow disks and that would hurt your performance).

Comment: KVM can overcommit memory and so can Xen.

Comment: @dyasny I don't know about KVM but I'm pretty sure Xen cannot *overcommit* memory in the actual sense of the word (allowing a different maximum size is a different thing). Please link your sources if you believe it does.

Comment: Xen supports balooning. Add standard swapping to this and you already have at least 2 overcommit mechanisms. This is as old as 2008: http://blog.xen.org/index.php/2008/08/27/xen-33-feature-memory-overcommit/

Comment: @dyasny you probably think about *overcommit* as allowing an higher maximum. AFAIK, the accepted meaning is to actually allocate to guests more memory than physically present in the host, and this is not implemented in Xen. You can't deflate a guest balloon (eg. give it more memory) if you don't have available physical memory in the host, and you cannot either start a new guest if you have already allocated all your host memory (unless you inflate running guests balloons, thus actually reducing allocated memory so you don't overcommit anything).

Comment: @dyasny and in addition to that, the hypervisor does not even know what swap is so it can't swap out memory pages. Making guests swap because they have less memory than they'd like is not what I call *overcommit*, it's just plain simple memory management within the guest when you take memory out of it.

Comment: I think about _overcommit_ as not only allowing more than the host physically has, but also as actually using more than the host physically has. Swapping is horrible, but it's a mechanism that allows you to allocate more memory pages than you physically have on a host, whether for processes, or VMs - doesn't matter. This is as far as I will go into semantics on this one.